# Is it possible to search of a text in SSRS via Filters?

Tags: reporting-services

I would like to have a multiple values Paramter with text1, text2, text3

SSRS should only show me the rows that **contain** one or all of this Parameter values in a column.

I notice you can set a filter in a Dataset or the tablix. The problem is I do not have something a function that do both **LIKE** and **IN**

Do you someone have an idea?

I tried already the LIKE function and the VALUE `=”*”+”Parameters!PAR.Value”+”*”.`
It did work, but not on a multiple values parameter.

[image: SSRS Filter]

Answer (score 0):

I don't *think* you will be able to do this using dataset filters using a multi-value parameter.

However, you should be able to change your dataset query to handle this.

```
CREATE PROC myProc (@myParameter varchar(1000))
AS
SELECT * FROM myTable t 
        JOIN string_split(@myParameter, ',') p on t.myColumn like '%' + p.value + '%'
```

When you pass the parameter to the stored proc you can use the following expression

```
=JOIN(Parameters!myParameter.Value, ",")
```

This will simply join each of your parameter values into a single comma separated string string ready to pass to the procedure.

---

If you do not have a version of SQL Server that support string_split

---

Hers's the code to create one. There are smaller versions around on the internet but this one was designed to handle special cases as well as the typical single character delimiters.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE  FUNCTION [Split](@sText varchar(8000), @sDelim varchar(20) = ' ')
RETURNS @retArray TABLE (idx smallint Primary Key, value varchar(8000))
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @idx smallint,
    @value varchar(8000),
    @bcontinue bit,
    @iStrike smallint,
    @iDelimlength tinyint
IF @sDelim = 'Space'
    BEGIN
    SET @sDelim = ' '
    END
SET @idx = 0
SET @sText = LTrim(RTrim(@sText))
SET @iDelimlength = DATALENGTH(@sDelim)
SET @bcontinue = 1
IF NOT ((@iDelimlength = 0) or (@sDelim = 'Empty'))
    BEGIN
    WHILE @bcontinue = 1
        BEGIN
--If you can find the delimiter in the text, retrieve the first element and
--insert it with its index into the return table.
 
        IF CHARINDEX(@sDelim, @sText)>0
            BEGIN
            SET @value = SUBSTRING(@sText,1, CHARINDEX(@sDelim,@sText)-1)
                BEGIN
                INSERT @retArray (idx, value)
                VALUES (@idx, @value)
                END
            
--Trim the element and its delimiter from the front of the string.
            --Increment the index and loop.
SET @iStrike = DATALENGTH(@value) + @iDelimlength
            SET @idx = @idx + 1
            SET @sText = LTrim(Right(@sText,DATALENGTH(@sText) - @iStrike))
        
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
--If you can't find the delimiter in the text, @sText is the last value in
--@retArray.
 SET @value = @sText
                BEGIN
                INSERT @retArray (idx, value)
                VALUES (@idx, @value)
                END
            --Exit the WHILE loop.
SET @bcontinue = 0
            END
        END
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
    WHILE @bcontinue=1
        BEGIN
        --If the delimiter is an empty string, check for remaining text
        --instead of a delimiter. Insert the first character into the
        --retArray table. Trim the character from the front of the string.
--Increment the index and loop.
        IF DATALENGTH(@sText)>1
            BEGIN
            SET @value = SUBSTRING(@sText,1,1)
                BEGIN
                INSERT @retArray (idx, value)
                VALUES (@idx, @value)
                END
            SET @idx = @idx+1
            SET @sText = SUBSTRING(@sText,2,DATALENGTH(@sText)-1)
            
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
            --One character remains.
            --Insert the character, and exit the WHILE loop.
            INSERT @retArray (idx, value)
            VALUES (@idx, @sText)
            SET @bcontinue = 0  
            END
    END
END
RETURN
END


GO
```

To test this  try something like

```
select * from Split('abc,def,ghi', ',')
```

which will return

[image]

Comment: I tried to use SQL CONTAIN on the main dataset 
SELECT Name
FROM [AdventureWorksLT2019].[SalesLT].[Product]
WHERE CONTAINS(name,  @PAR )  and =JOIN(Parameters!@PAR.Value, " OR ") as Parameter Value Input. It DOES WORK with multiple specify values, but not with "get parameter values from a query".  Very weird.

Comment: Do you know why it does not work properly, if I use "get parameter values from a query" at the Paramter properties?

Comment: It is because the "get parameter from a query" contain text with space.

Comment: I'm not sure and I don't have a database setup that supports CONTAINS to test. What I would do is to run a trace on your session and see exactly what query is being executed on the server, that point you in the right direction. It might be that you have to wrap the text in `*`s something like `="*" & JOIN(Parameters!@PAR.Value, "* OR *") & "*"`, but thats just a guess

Comment: I found the solution for that problem. You have to create the parameter values with '"'+name + '"'. But a new problem arrived, if you concat all you Parameter values with OR into one cell. The problem is that that cell can be to big for SQL Server and an error occure.

Comment: In that case I would look at my original answer and make the parameter size bigger. If that doesn't work I'm not sure what to suggest as you somehow have to pass that large parameter to your query

Comment: I can not use SELECT * FROM myTable t 
        JOIN string_split(@myParameter, ',') p on t.myColumn like '%' + p.value + '%'. It does not work. "Query execution failed because of false object name string _split "?

Comment: I guess you are using an old version of SQL Server. string_split was introduced in SQL2016 I think. You would have to write your own but there are dozens of examples out there for a string splitting function. I'll add the one we used to use to the answer (back in the sql 2008 days) .